# return different directory when using bower install component on different server

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install, bower-register

my webapp use bower to build the js dependency,and jquery-ui.js is required,so I add jquery-ui to bower.json.

But when I run bower install on different servers,the result is different,on one server,the directory is app/components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js 
and on another server the directory is app/components/jqueryui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js

why different result? I have google a lot but only find this answer
https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/192, but still can't figure out what's the root cause, what may cause this result? different bower config on two servers?

Thank you !

Comment: I can see one server fetch code from https://github.com/components/jqueryui and another from https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui

Comment: it's firewall issue, when network not work, can not reach some components cause download terminate.